# Ubuntu 18.04 add to input source not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: language-support

In "Language and Region", the Language is "English" and formats is set to "Australia".

I tried to add "French" to input sources - it displays "French" but pressing "Add" is not working.

I tried again, added "Greek" , no problem, then tried add "French(alt.)" and that worked, still wondering why "French(France)" is not accepted. Could it be a keyboard problem ? My keyboard is "qwerty" is it expecting "azerty" keyboard ?

Comment: Please define "is not working".

Comment: in "SETTINGS" on the left you have the options, one option is "Language and Region" , pressing Enter on "Language and Region" gives on the right "Input Sources" , under "Input Sources" there is a list of language(s) installed. Under the list there is a "+" sign to add a language. When I add "Greek" the language "Greek" is added, so I say : it works. When I add "French(alt.)" the language is added, so I say: it works. When I add "French" nothing happens, so I say: it does not work.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Just tried it myself. When I clicked _French (France)_, a sub menu opened and there I could successfully add _French_. Does that possibly help?

Comment: Yes it does help, if it works for you and not for me then the problem is with my computer. Thanks.

Comment: That's weird. Can it be that the file with the French layouts is corrupted for you? One idea: Run `sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data` and then reboot.

Comment: Tried that, rebooted, same. Thanks for your time, decided to give up,  accentuated chars are a pain in the neck but I can manage from a text file with list of chars. Decided it is a  'minor inconvenience'  !

Comment: hi @BobRun, running into similar issue today, did you find a fix on your side? Thanks,